# traverse and get file name only?

Tags: java, java-8

I want to traverse through the directories and get the file name only discarding the path?i tried through java 8 walk method but paths are getting printed along with file name.

Here is what I have tried as of now:

- This can not traverse to the end but print the recent file name.

```
    File folder = new File("E:\\Netbeans_Don't_Delete\\Testing");
    File[] listOfFiles =    folder.   listFiles  ();

    for(
    int i = 0;i<listOfFiles.length;i++)
    {
        if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
            System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
        }
    }
```

- This can traverse but print the whole path but i want the file name which will be in the end

```
   try(

        Stream<Path> paths = 
                    Files.walk(Paths.get("E:\\Netbeans_Don't_Delete\\Testing")))
        paths.filter(Files::isRegularFile).forEach(System.out::println);
      }
```

Comment: What is wrong with method no 1? @ayaan khan

Comment: @Pie it couldn't  traverse to the end for fetching the file name.

Comment: I used it. It worked fine. Program output see screenshots https://imgur.com/a/EGL0ku3 File explorer output https://imgur.com/a/PtTNbWV @ayaan khan

Comment: try with multiple sub-folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`getFileName`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#getFileName--) to get the name of the file.

```
paths
    .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
    .forEach(path -> System.out.println(path.getFileName()));
```

Comment: can you please convert it into a List<string> type

Comment: This should do that `paths.filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                .map(Path::getFileName)
                .collect(Collectors.toList())`